# How do I write styles for the disabled checked state?

Tags: html, css, sass

How do I write styles for the disabled checked state ?

[image: Appearance of the checkbox]

I do not know how to make the toggler change color in this state, without very complex designs. I am forbidden by styling to build complex multi-level structures with selectors. The nesting should be no more than 3 levels. Please use as many examples as possible in the answer for easy understanding.

My html

```html
<fieldset class="filters__group filter-country">
          <legend class="filters__title">Страна произрастания</legend>
          <ul class="filters__list filter-country__list">
            <li class="filters__item filter-country__item">
              <input class="filter-country__control visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="country-brazil" name="country" value="brazil" checked>
              <label class="filter-country__text" for="country-brazil">Бразилия</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filters__item filter-country__item">
              <input class="filter-country__control visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="country-ethiopia" name="country" value="ethiopia">
              <label class="filter-country__text" for="country-ethiopia">Эфиопия</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filters__item filter-country__item">
              <input class="filter-country__control visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="country-colombia" name="country" value="colombia">
              <label class="filter-country__text" for="country-colombia">Колумбия</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filters__item filter-country__item">
              <input class="filter-country__control visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="country-costa-rica" name="country" value="costa-rica" disabled>
              <label class="filter-country__text" for="country-costa-rica">Коста-Рика</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filters__item filter-country__item">
              <input class="filter-country__control visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="country-peru" name="country" value="peru"  disabled>
              <label class="filter-country__text" for="country-peru">Перу</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </fieldset>
```

My scss

```scss
.filter-country__text {
  --color: #bdbdbd;
  --control-color: #f8f8f8;
  --border-color: #bdbdbd;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 52px;

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 42px;
    height: 21px;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: var(--color);
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
  }

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--control-color);
    left: 2px;
    top: 2.2px;
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
  }
}

.filter-country__control {
  --color: #bdbdbd;
  --control-color: #f8f8f8;
  appearance: none;

  &:checked + .filter-country__text {
    &::before {
      --color: hsl(256 76% 68% / 1);
      --border-color: hsl(256 76% 68% / 1);
    }

    &::after {
      left: 23.5px;
    }
  }

  &:hover + .filter-country__text,
  &:focus-visible + .filter-country__text {
    &::before {
      --color: hsl(256 55% 58% / 0.25);
      --border-color: hsl(256 76% 68% / 1);
    }
  }

  &:disabled + .filter-country__text {
    color: hsl(0 0% 74% / 1);

    &::before {
      --color: hsl(0 0% 89% / 1);
      --border-color: hsl(0 0% 89% / 1);
    }

    &::after {
      --control-color: hsl(0 0% 97% / 1);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the solution I proposed. Do you have better options?

```scss
&:disabled.filter-country__control:checked + .filter-country__text {
    &::after {
      --control-color: hsl(0 0% 74% / 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the solution you propose work?  If so, what are you looking to improved about it?

Comment: If you provided CSS you would probably get more answers because answerers could use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)...